# dd input/output error. No information in error string

Tags: macos, usb, hardware

I am using a MacBook macOS Mojave 10.14.5. I can list the device with `diskutil list`, but it isn't mounted. I perform the `dd` command below. The output states `input/output error`, which doesn't give a lot of information.

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2s2 
Password:
dd: /dev/rdisk2s2: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 80.936791 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you write a few blocks of zero?
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2s2 bs=4096 count=8` and why are you writing to the raw disk instead of the disk itself or using disk utility app to restore the image with help?

Comment: With the target disk attached to the Mac, what it the full output of `diskutil list` in **Terminal**? Add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bootable flash drive, follow the Ubuntu help:

- This will be easier since there is the Etcher app you download to avoid the direct use of the `dd` command.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0

While I recommend using the Ubuntu ISO image with Etcher, my comments on the use of the `dd` command follow. You seem to be following the instructions from the link below. You got the wrong device name, `/dev/rdisk2s2`. You need the disk name not the partition name. You should remove all external drives except your flash drive.  This will make it easier to identify the flash drive and reduce the risk from using the `dd` command. Try the instructions again from the beginning.

https://itsfoss.com/create-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-mac-os/

Comment: Good call using etcher. Much better than my recommendation to use Disk Utility since they both try to get around the risk of someone using dd at the command line to destroy the wrong disk.

Comment: Thanks historystamp. I had some other URLs but  yours are more current.